# Ребят, подскажите, как можно сократить мой код?

Tags: php, вконтакте

index.php

```
<br>
<center>
<?
    $post = $vk->getWall();
    echo "<h3>".$post[0]->text."</h3>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($post[0]->attachments); $i++) {
        if ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[9]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[9]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[8]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[8]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[7]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[7]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[6]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[6]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[5]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[5]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[4]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[4]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[3]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[3]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[2]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[2]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[1]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[1]->url."'><br><br>";
        } elseif ($post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[0]->url != NULL) {
            echo "<img src='".$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[0]->url."'><br><br>";
        }
    }
?>
</center>
<br>
```

Метод getWall()

```
public function getWall(){
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php';
    $request_params = array(
        'owner_id' => $vk_id,
        'v' => '5.100',
        'count' => '1',
        'filter' => 'owner',
        'access_token' => $app_service
    );
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?'.$get_params));
    return $result->response->items;
}
```

Comment: вам поможет команда break в for цикле по условию https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php

Comment: `$post = current($post)` избавит вас от писанины `[0]` в каждый раз, коли вы работаете только с первым элементом массива. Дабы не писать каждый раз `$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes` вынесите в самом начале цикла это в отдельную переменную `$psize`. А дальше ваш алгоритм не ясен, что вы вообще делаете

Comment: видимо вам нужно сделать вложенный цикл, за место того, чтобы писать `$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[4]->url`, чтобы было так: `$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[$t]->url` например. И будет 2 цикла и 1 строчка в них. Заместо тучи строк, а если их будут 100тни:? Вы сто+ раз будете писать `$post[0]->attachments[$i]->photo->sizes[4]->url`? =)) Ну или рекурсия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `index.php` как вариант:

```
$post = $vk->getWall();
echo "<h3>".$post[0]->text."</h3>";

foreach ($post[0]->attachments as $item){
    for($i = 9; $i >= 0; $i--){
        if($item->photo->sizes[$i]->url != NULL){
            echo "<img src='".$item->photo->sizes[$i]->url."'><br><br>";
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Но со 100% точностью сложно сказать, т.к. не совсем понятно что приходит в переменную `$post`

Comment: «что приходит в переменную $post» — https://vk.com/dev/objects/post / https://vk.com/dev/wall.get